# Adding templateUrl dynamically while setting $routeProvider $ angular.config

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing, angularjs-provider, angularjs-rootscope

I am angular newbie.I would like to achieve following code...

```
 $routeProvider.when('/view', {templateUrl: 'ViewSwitcher?pageId='+$rootSope.pageId+'&userId='+$rootSope..userId+'&token='+$rootScope.token, controller: ''});
```

ViewSwitcher is a servelet which responses me a HTML page as per pageId,userId(saved in $rootScope)  ......but $rootScope is not available....Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do one thing here instead of store this variables inside the `$rootScope` use `provider` that could be easily accessible inside the config phase. Create one `myData` provider that would share a data between different components of your app.

**Code**

```
//before using `myDataProvider` make sure it has been injected as dependency.
$routeProvider.when('/view', {
    templateUrl: 'ViewSwitcher?pageId='+myDataProvider.pageId+'&userId='+ myDataProvider.userId+'&token='+ myDataProvider.token,
    controller: 'myCtrl' //<--here it should be some controller
});
```

Comment: Thanks Pankaj for your valuable reply......I have defined provider like this : myApp.provider('configurableProvider', function () {
  var name = 'xyz';
  this.setName = function (newName) {
  name = newName;
  };
  this.$get = function () {
  return name;
  };
 });      and  using like      myApp.config(['$routeProvider','configurableProvider', function ($routeProvider,configurableProvider) {        ...........but getting error unknown provider(i think wrong injection) ......

Comment: @AKRICK your provider name should be `configurable` only..while using it in configuration phase you need to post fix it with `Provider` like it will used as `configurableProvider` & other than config phase you could use that by `configurable`

Comment: at Pankaj: done all fixes .running but still getting undefined in url......pharmApp.config(['$routeProvider','configurableProvider', function ($routeProvider,configurable) {....................

Comment: could you update you question with what you have tried till?

Comment: I achieved using ...App.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
 $routeProvider.when('/view1', {templateUrl: function(configurable){
  debugger;
  var obj=angular.element('*[ng-app]').injector().get("configurable");
  return 'ViewSwitcher?pageId='+obj.pageId+'&userId='+obj.userId+'&token='+obj.token;
  }, controller: '' });        ................thanks !